# Create websocket without connecting

Tags: javascript, websocket

Is there a way to create a websocket without connecting to it right away?
So far I think

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://ws.my.url.com");
```

creates and then connects right away.

I'd like to create the socket, define the callbacks, and then connect once the user clicks a connect button.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  Creating a webSocket means you've created a connection to a server (or started the process of connecting).  There is no such thing as creating a webSocket that isn't connecting yet.

You could create an object that would store all the configuration parameters and then just tell that object to connect when you wanted to, though I'm not really sure why that's better than just creating the actual webSocket when you the connection to be made.

Or just create a function that does all the setup work and call that function later when the user clicks a connect button.